# processor running continuously at 100%

Tags: windows-10, cpu-usage

HP elitebook 840 G3
windows 10 pro 64bit
PROCESSOR (i5 6300U)

processor continuously runs at 100%

key services:

HP network prioritizer  ~27% - very high power requirement

MS Windows search protocol host  13%  very high power requirement

Google Drive  30%  very high power requirement

System   7%

Processor running very hot

SSD running at 45C

Any suggestions on how to  reduce processor requirements and lower the temperatures

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use Windows 10 built in Resource Monitor. Admin Tools, Resource Monitor.

Let it run for 15 to 20 minutes. Then see what specific processes come to the top in terms of CPU usage.

Do a Full scan with Windows Defender as you may have a virus.

A properly running i5 / i7 should run at < 5% CPU more than 95% of the time.

[image]